# Summing over multiple fields in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, sum, eloquent, query-builder

I'm wondering if it is possible to take the sum of multiple fields in one query using the fluent query builder.

For exemple :

```
SELECT sum(nb_visit + nb_recommendation)
FROM Stats 
GROUP BY id
```

So far is what i have :

```
Stats::sum('nb_visit+nb_recommendation');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QueryBuilder to do this:

```
DB::table('stats')
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(nb_visit + nb_recommendation)'))
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Ok ok ! thx i already knew that. I was really looking for Eloquent way to do that. 
But sum() expects a string  :-/